# Dynamically index a specific element in an n-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have an n-dimensional bool numpy array. I want to invert the bool value of a random item in the array. Inverting is easy, but I'm not sure how to best index a random element. I can generate a list of random positions along the n dimensions

```
indices = [np.random.randint(n) for n in array.shape]
```

However, how do I use that to index the corresponding element? `array[indices]` fetches elements at indices along the first dimension. `array[*indices]` does not work. I could do something like

```
a = array[indices[0]]
for index in indices[1:]:
    a = a[index]
```

but I'd like to avoid loops. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: `[(*indices,)]` will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this sound too simple, but use a tuple instead of a list for the index. There's some documentation about why this is in the [Numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), but (at least for me) the significance of tuples isn't immediately obvious (even though it was quite clear and there's a big warning box about this).

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(201)

A = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=(2,2))

# make it a Tuple
index = tuple(np.random.randint(n) for n in A.shape)

print(A)
# [[False True]
#  [False  True]]

print(index)
# (0, 1)

print(A[index])
# True

A[index] = ~A[index]
print(A)

# [[False  False]
#  [False  True]]
```

Comment: Why not just `np.randint(a.shape)`?

Comment: Yeah, @MadPhysicist that's a cleaner way to make the array. I suppose the main point of the answer is that would *still* need to be turned into a tuple to use it the way the OP wants and avoid triggering advanced indexing.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I don't find this syntax to be very intuitive but I will sure remember it now.

Comment: It helps me to remember that `a[3,4,2]` is really `a[(3,4,2)]`.  The index is a tuple, with one element per dimension.  It's the comma that creates the tuple, the () are not always necessary.